# stopping the click event handler on a certain condition

Tags: javascript

i am trying to create an image gallery here.
I have my images in an array.
Now on previous button click what i do is i change the previous picture index to
`currentindex-1`.

And then  i set the current picture element to `currentIndex+1`;
And then grab all the details from the current index like file path for big image and all.
Now my question is

for the first image with say index 0 when the currentIndex results in 0;How can i 
disable the previous button click. so that it stops when there is no  images left i mean the `previousIndex=0` Please tell me, thanks.

Comment: Add code, maybe there are tons of solutions

Comment: With some code snippet, the answer could be more specific. I agree with @MarcosPérezGude here

Answer (score 3):

The following line of code will help to disable the button, So at first when the page loads keep the previous button in disable. Once user click on next button enable the previous button and on each previous button click determine weather you need to disable or enable the button.

```
document.getElementById("id").disabled = true; //false to enable the button back
```

Comment: @Kishore and How to Enable that?

Comment: I mean disabled=false;

Comment: @Kishore it's a span element with an image of left arrow in it.. So will .disable work on that element?

Comment: Since, as you said, it is span with image, I would rather wrap your code for changing index of current image with an if statement and check if it is already 0. If yes, just don't change index and do not load previous image.

Comment: @Marc: No disbable property wont work on span elements but if you gave your onclick event to the button you can the function triggering